# Using an 'fmap-like' function on types of kind *

Tags: haskell, type-kinds

Say we have a data type defined as

```
data A a = A' a deriving Show
```

We have

```
A :: * -> *
```

We can then make A an instance of `Functor`:

```
instance Functor A where fmap f (A' x) = A' (f x)
```

This allows us to make a value of type `A` and use `fmap` to apply a function to the wrapped value

```
Prelude> let x = A' 1
Prelude> fmap (+1) x
A' 2
```

Now, if we defined `A` as

```
data A = A' Int deriving Show
```

The kind of `A` is

```
A :: *
```

Consequently, we can not make `A` an instance of Functor -

```
instance Functor A where fmap f (A' x) = A' (f x)

<interactive>:4:18:
    Kind mis-match
    The first argument of `Functor' should have kind `* -> *',
    but `A' has kind `*'
    In the instance declaration for `Functor A'
```

My question is, is there a generic way to apply a function to the wrap value for data types of kind `*` with a data constructor that only takes one parameter (i.e., something analogous to `fmap`)? It's fairly easy to write custom function:

```
Prelude> let myFmap f (A' x) = A' (f x)
Prelude> let x = A' 1
Prelude> myFmap (+1) x
A' 2
```

It's also possible to make `A` an instance of `Num`:

```
instance Num A where (+) (A' x) (A' y) = A' (x + y) -- Ignoring the warnings
Prelude> A' 1 + A' 1 
A' 2
```

Both of these approaches work but is there a better way that I am missing?

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there's a good generic solution for the second half of the question, but I can at least answer the first half.

This is the purpose of the [mono-traversable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable) package, which provides a [`MonoFunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-0.10.0/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFunctor) typeclass. The instance for `A'` would be:

```
type instance Element A' = Int

instance MonoFunctor a' where
  omap f (A' i) = A' (f i)
```

YMMV on how useful this is versus a simple `a'map :: (Int -> Int) -> A' -> A'` function or a lens.

Comment: Note, `iso` and probably `Wrapped` in the `lens` package allows to do similar things.